# IDictionary duplicate merging - add or update to existing object

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, hashcode

I'll do my best to explain what I'm doing here - I have used this approach a few times but have never felt that good about it.  I am sure there must be a better way of doing it, please enlighten me.

```
class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(MyObject))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return ((MyObject)obj).Id == Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id;
    }
}

[Test]
public void Blah()
{
    IDictionary<object, MyObject> duplicateMergerDict = new Dictionary<object, MyObject>();

    MyObject dup1 = new MyObject { Id = 0, Name = "Smith" };
    MyObject dup2 = new MyObject { Id = 0, Name = "Collins" };
    MyObject nonDup = new MyObject { Id = 1, Name = "Smith" };

    IEnumerable<MyObject> test =
        new[] { dup1, dup2, nonDup };

    foreach (var myObject in test)
    {
        MyObject existing;
        if (duplicateMergerDict.TryGetValue(myObject, out existing))
        {
            existing.Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", existing.Name, myObject.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            duplicateMergerDict.Add(myObject, myObject);
        }
    }

    Assert.That(duplicateMergerDict.Count, Is.EqualTo(2));

    Assert.That(duplicateMergerDict[dup1], Is.SameAs(dup1));
    Assert.That(duplicateMergerDict[dup2], Is.SameAs(dup1));

    Assert.That(dup1.Name, Is.EqualTo("Smith Collins"));

    Assert.That(duplicateMergerDict[nonDup], Is.SameAs(nonDup));
}
```

Basically I want to accumulate duplicate entries using GetHashCode and Equals overriding.  (Or should I use a composite key object - even for much more complex cases than this?).  The method above seems messy but perhaps it's the best way?

Can someone wiser than me please show me where I can improve on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `test.Distinct()` simply? This returns 2 items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Basically I want to accumulate duplicate entries using GetHashCode and Equals overriding.

You can't. That's not what they're there for. They are *solely* present to find a key, testing it for equality. You certainly shouldn't be mutating anything in there.

Your approach using `TryGetValue` works, but it requires that your values are mutable, which isn't pleasant IMO. You might want to look at `ConcurrentDictionary<,>` though, which has a handy [`AddOrUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378675.aspx) method which sounds like it does exactly what you want.